# Facebook: How to generate fb comments code for each individual posts of my blog

Tags: javascript, python, facebook, plugins, web

I have a blog which has various posts so I tried to incorporate facebook comments to my posts but it only generates the code for a single url.Suppose I have the post whose url is 'example.com/post1',I enter this in facebook comments code generator and I get the code for showing fb comments on that particular post.But how about if I have few more posts like 'example.com/post2' etc.How can I get fb comments for each of my posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll show you some of my code from my website in PHP.

I include the Javascript SDK first, which I assume you have done.

Then I use the following code.

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="[your site url]/post[post id]" data-num-posts="2" data-width="470"></div>
```

Connor

Comment: Then use the code I posted and replace [your site url] with your domain name then [post id] with the current post ID.

Comment: But if I do that,the same comment thread shows on each and every post.

Comment: Your individual blog posts have unique URLs don't they? Do you know how to generate dynamic URLs for your blog posts? For example, you'll need to know some PHP if you're using Wordpress.

Answer (score 2):

What would be equivalent for joomla:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" data-num-posts="2" data-width="470"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What blogging platform are you using? Is it a custom one or something like Wordpress?

If you're using wordpress, you can simply add the following code where you want the comments to appear and it will grab the current post url (this will require php)

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" data-num-posts="2" data-width="470"></div>
```

if its not a wordpress blog, you can use PHP to request the current url of the page, which should allow comments for each individual page

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?php $url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; echo $url;?>" data-num-posts="2" data-width="470"></div>
```

I'm definitely not a PHP expert, but have used these two methods successfully in the past

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?php $url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; echo $url;?>" data-num-posts="2" data-width="470"></div>
```

plus add the facebook JS code.

using

```
<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>
```

will not work